# Adding LUTs and film grain overlays to raspicam

Tags: raspbian, python, raspicam, picamera

learning python and such by coding and building a camera using the High Quality Camera. Being able to code physical inputs to control the various camera functions was a major win for me, so I don’t know much at all when it comes to the finer points of python.

I’m trying to figure out how I would go about taking the raw video data, adding a custom Color LUT and a film grain overlay, and then packaging that all together into the recorded file. Is anyone familiar enough with the legacy raspicam to help me get started with that?